# How use return 'stdout' into module

Tags: ansible

How can I use `until` with data that returned by a module, `ios_module`? I need to find the maximum transmission unit (MTU) that can pass. If the packet pass the output will have "!!!!".

```yaml
- name: Test mtu size
  ios_command:
    commands:
      - command: 'ping 10.10.10.10 df-bit size {{ pkt_size + 5 }}  repeat 4'
    provider: "{{ cli }}"          
  register: dump
  until: '"!!!!" in stdout'
```

Comment: Except for checking `dump.stdout` as [the manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops) clearly specifies, what is the problem with the code?

Comment: If run playbook the task fails:
fatal: [10.10.10.10]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The conditional check 'escape in stdout' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (escape in stdout): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if escape in stdout %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/gorobec/ansible/mtu.yml': line 12, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the...

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation [Retrying a task until a condition is met](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) it seems you are missing some parameters as mentioned in the example there. You could try a test like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  vars:

    PING_COUNT: "3"

  tasks:

  - name: Ping until
    shell:
      cmd: ping -c {{ PING_COUNT }} $(hostname)
    register: result
    until: result.stdout.find("icmp_seq=4") != -1
    retries: 5
    delay: 2

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

which would fail for a `PING_COUNT: "3"` but successful for a `PING_COUNT: "5"`.

What will **not** work is using the outer task counter `attempts` within the inner task command.

```yaml
  - name: Ping until
    shell:
      cmd: ping -c {{ result.attempts | default('1') }} $(hostname)
    register: result
    until: result.stdout.find("icmp_seq=4") != -1
    retries: 5
    delay: 2
```

The job will be compiled with the initial counter and stay with the value and execution will result into

```
TASK [Echo until] ******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true
  attempts: 5
  cmd: ping -c 1 $(hostname)
  ...
  stdout: |-
    PING test.example.com (93.184.216.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from test.example.com (93.184.216.34): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms

    --- test.example.com ping statistics ---
    1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
  ...
```

If it is necessary to count within the command the following approach might help.

```yaml
  - name: Ping until
    shell:
      cmd: ping -c {{ item }}  $(hostname)
    register: result
    with_sequence:
      - "1-5"
    until: result.stdout.find("icmp_seq=4") != -1
    retries: 1
```