# Ansible: How to ICMP ping to check on host?

Tags: linux, networking, ansible, devops, icmp

Im having some trouble with an Ansible setup. I need to check before executing my whole playbook if the host is available by ICMP, and if there's no reply, I want to skip that host from the execution of the playbook.

My current playbook is the following:

```yaml
---
- name: Auto_backup_test
  gather_facts: False
  hosts: all
  become: false

  tasks:
    - name: Connection-ping
      delegate_to: localhost
      command: ping -c 2 "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      register: router_ping

    - name: print_response
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: router_ping.rc
        verbosity: 2
```

So, the playbook should execute two ICMP pings requests, and save the result in the `router_ping` register.

After that I want it to check with the `router_ping.rc` value if the request failed and usig that I decide if the host is `skipped` or not.

When I execute the playbook using this command:

```bash
ansible-playbook -i /my_inventory/ playbook.yml -vvv
```

In my inventory I have 2 hosts, one that should be able to reply ICMP, and another IP that doesn't exist, so that host should fail.

The output is the following:

[image: First host output]

[image: Second host output]

As this can be seen, the host that replies the ICMP request works fine.

But when the host does not reply the ICMP request, the task ends failing and the register `router_ping` ends not being created, so I cannot use that register. The output of the second host is the what we want but, is not creating the register, so I cannot evaluate the `router_ping.rc` value to check if the host is available.

How could I be doing this to perform better?

I also tried using the `ansible.builtin.ping` module, but as this does not works as I thought as it always outputs SUCCESS, so it doesn't work for me.

I tried with this for a while to make it work, but I end always getting Success output even though the IP address of the host doesn't exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible: will it skip to next task if the current task failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67673567/ansible-will-it-skip-to-next-task-if-the-current-task-failed)

Comment: I like to recommend to use an approach like under [Ansible: How to `icmp_ping` from one Remote Node to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75149464/6771046) instead of `command: ping ...` since that might be easier to work with.

Comment: I would not depend on an ICMP ping because hosts can be configured to ignore ICMP echo requests, and many people think that is a smart thing to do.

Comment: Abdul Aziz Barkat: it is not exactly what I need but thanks, I could use it in another thing.

 
U880D: In my case I need to perform ping from the ansible server to the hosts, so from localhost.

Ron Maupin: The devices are managed by me, so I have them configured to accept ICMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: ICMP ping from Control Node to Remote Node
    delegate_to: localhost # or controlnode.example.com
    command: ping -c 2 "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    # Because it is an reporting task
    changed_when: false 
    check_mode: false
    failed_when: router_ping.rc == 1 or router_ping.rc > 2 # will result into success for rc 0 and rc 2
    register: router_ping

  - name: Show Return Code
    debug:
      msg: "{{ router_ping.rc }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [ICMP ping from Control Node to Remote Node] ******
ok: [test1.example.com -> localhost]
ok: [test1.nonexisting.example.com -> localhost]
ok: [test2.example.com -> localhost]
ok: [test2.nonexisting.example.com -> localhost]

TASK [Show Return Code] ********************************
ok: [test1.example.com] =>
  msg: '0'
ok: [test1.nonexisting.example.com] =>
  msg: '2'
ok: [test2.example.com] =>
  msg: '0'
ok: [test2.nonexisting.example.com] =>
  msg: '2'

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
test1.nonexisting.example.com : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
test1.example.com  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
test2.example.com : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
test2.nonexisting.example.com  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

With this (`router_ping.rc`) one could test if the host is resolvable and reachable (`0`) or not (`2`). However, this seems to be not a good practice for further playbook processing and since Ansible has already some handling for unreachable hosts implemented.

**Further Documentation**

- [Error handling in playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html)

and I like to recommend to read about

- [Ansible: How to `icmp_ping` from one Remote Node to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75149464/6771046)

Finally a somehow

**Similar Q&A**

- [How can I use `until` with data that returned by a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70998838/6771046)

---